# I keep getting list out of range trying to convert mysqldatabase into html

Tags: python, html, mysql

I dont get why it keeps giving me the list out of range error for sys.argv[1]. From my understanding I am passing data to user_database. Help please

```
import sys, MySQLdb

def PrintFields(database, table):
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'boysnblue1'
    conn = MySQLdb.Connection(db=parking_report, host=localhost, user=root, passwd=boysnblue1)
    mysql = conn.cursor()
    sql = """ SHOW COLUMNS FROM %s """ % table
    mysql.execute("select id, date, time, status, from report_table ")
    fields=mysql.fetchall()
    print '<table border="0"><tr><th>order</th><th>name</th><th>type</th><th>description</th></tr>'
    print '<tbody>'
    counter = 0
    for field in fields:
        counter = counter + 1
        id = field[0]
        date = field[1]
        time = field[2]
        status = field[3]
        print '<tr><td>' + str(counter) + '</td><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + time + '</td><td>' + status + ' </td></tr>'
    print '</tbody>'
    print '</table>'
    mysql.close()
    conn.close()

users_database = sys.argv[1]
users_table = sys.argv[2]
print "Wikified HTML for " + users_database + "." + users_table
print "========================"
PrintFields(users_database, users_table)
```

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` means the first command-line argument. Are you calling this as `python your_file.py some_arg some_other_arg`?

Comment: excuse my ignorance I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: How are you invoking the script you posted? How do you run your program?

Comment: Im running it by using python script2.py

Comment: You have your answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list containing the name of the program's file and all of the arguments it was passed on the command line.

If you run `python script2.py`, the contents of `sys.argv` will be `['script2.py']`.

If you run `python script2.py database_name table_name`, the contents of `sys.argv` will be `['script2.py', 'database_name', 'table_name']`, which is what your program is currently configured to expect:

```
users_database = sys.argv[1]
users_table = sys.argv[2]
```

Since you are calling it the first way, `sys.argv[1]` does not exist, and you get your error that the index (1) is out of range (it only goes to 0).

Comment: Running that gave me a bunch of errors which is helping me get on the road to solving my problem. Thank you.